# How to use \appto in nested macro

Tags: etoolbox

By the following code, I tried to make the macro `myexe` store this code: `\colorbox{red}{\parbox{1in}{some text}}` and failed.

How can I do it?

CODE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}
\def\fortestpaper{
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
}
\fortestpaper
\begin{document}
\def\mycolor{red}
\def\mylength{1in}
\def\myexe{}

% The following code tries to construct \colorbox{red}{\parbox{1in}{some text}}
\appto\myexe{\colorbox}
\eappto\myexe{{\mycolor}}
\appto\myexe{\{}
\appto\myexe{\parbox}
\eappto\myexe{{\mylength}{some text}}
\appto\myexe{\}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\myexe
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\def\myexe{\colorbox{red}{\parbox{1in}{some text}}}`? Or you have a further demand?

Comment: No. What I want is to construct `\myexe` by `\appto` from `etoolbox` for later invoke. In my reason, I don't define it derectly. I wonder if there is a way to handle the second pair of `{} ` of `\colorbox` by `\appto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is easier to concat tokens by using some `\unexpand` and `\noexpanded` inside `\eappto`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}
\def\fortestpaper{
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
}
\fortestpaper
\begin{document}

\def\mycolor{red}
\def\mylength{1in}
\def\myexe{}

% The following code tries to construct \colorbox{red}{\parbox{1in}{some text}}

\eappto\myexe{%
  \noexpand\colorbox{\mycolor}{%
    \noexpand\parbox{\mylength}{%
      \unexpanded{some text}%
    }%
  }%
}

\myexe

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between `unexpanded` and `noexpand`?

Comment: @lyl \noexpand for single token, \unexpanded for multiple tokens enclosed with braces.

Comment: If `\mylength` is replaced with `\dimexpr 2in - 1in`, I find it does not expand. Why since no `\noexpand` or `unexpanded` act on `dimexpr` ?

Comment: @lyl You need to add `\the` before `\dimexpr` to make it expand.

Comment: Why is `dimexpr` so special that needs `\the` to expand it? I have been regarding `\the\lengthmacro` as typeset(output to pdf) of the demenstion value.

Comment: @lyl It is the same for dimensions defined with \newlength.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get `\eappto` to work in the inner-grouped case; however, I could just pre-expand from prior to an `\appto` to achieve the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}
\def\fortestpaper{
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
}
\fortestpaper
\begin{document}
\def\mycolor{red}
\def\mylength{1in}
\def\myexe{}

% The following code tries to construct \colorbox{red}{\parbox{1in}{some text}}
\appto\myexe{\colorbox}
\eappto\myexe{\expandafter{\mycolor}}
\expandafter\appto\expandafter\myexe\expandafter{\expandafter{\expandafter
  \parbox\expandafter{\mylength}{some text}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\myexe

\colorbox{red}{\parbox{1in}{some text}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the `\{`, `\}` in your example as begin group, end group, then you can use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` instead them:

```
\let\ea=\expandafter
\long\def\addto#1#2{\ea\def\ea#1\ea{#1#2}}
\def\eaddto#1{\ea\addto\ea#1\ea}

\def\mycolor{red}
\def\mylength{1in}
\def\myexe{}

\addto\myexe{\colorbox}
\eaddto\myexe{\ea{\mycolor}}
\addto\myexe{\bgroup}
\addto\myexe{\parbox}
\eaddto\myexe{\ea{\mylength}}
\addto\myexe{{some text}}
\addto\myexe{\egroup}

\message{\meaning\myexe}
% macro:->\colorbox {red}\bgroup \parbox {1in}{some text}\egroup
```

If you really want to insert open brace in different time than close brace, then you must insert detokenized variants and use `\scantokens` before usage of your `\myexe`:

```
\let\ea=\expandafter
\long\def\addto#1#2{\ea\def\ea#1\ea{#1#2}}
\def\eaddto#1{\ea\addto\ea#1\ea}

\edef\bopen{\string{} \edef\bclose{\string}}

\def\mycolor{red}
\def\mylength{1in}
\def\myexe{}

\addto\myexe{\colorbox}
\eaddto\myexe{\ea{\mycolor}}
\eaddto\myexe{\bopen}
\addto\myexe{\parbox}
\eaddto\myexe{\ea{\mylength}}
\addto\myexe{{some text}}
\eaddto\myexe{\bclose}

\scantokens\ea{\ea\def\ea\myexe\ea{\myexe}}
\message{\meaning\myexe}
% macro:->\colorbox {red}{\parbox {1in}{some text}}
```

Comment: Thank you! And what's the difference between `\message{\meaning\myexe}` and `\show\myexe`?

Comment: `\show\myexe` ends with the TeX error, but `\message` is the message without any error.

Comment: where to find the message by `\message{\meaning\myexe}`? I don't find any message in the output pdf, but `\meaning\myexe` does.

Comment: `\message` puts its message to the terminal and to the log file. This is the same behavior as `\show`.